# Can't access Yahoo account on iphone- says 'IMAP server"apple.imap.mail.yahoo.com" isn't working'

Tags: iphone, imap

My yahoo account has stopped working on my iphone 4s.
I can access the account on a desktop but not the iphone.
Comes up with 'The IMAP server "apple.imap.mail.yahoo.com" is not responding. Check your network connection and that you entered the correct information in the "incoming Mail Server' field.'

Any idea how to fix this? Hasn't happened before.

Comment: reset that account, Delete and recreate.

Comment: I have deleted the account and added it back but having no luck. I added the account on an iphone 6 and it worked fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: check your firewall and privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

The incoming IMAP server you are getting ("IMAP.apple.mail.yahoo.com") is not a real Yahoo IMAP server. Like @Buscar said, deleting and re-adding should resolve the problem. However, it seems like the settings are getting recreating incorrectly.

What I'd do, after re-adding the email, is manually fix the settings to the right servers. To fix them, go to Settings > Mail, Contacts & Calendars > (select Yahoo account) > Account. You should have the option to edit the IMAP server in the Advanced section.

If it doesn't allow you to change it, add the account manually by going to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Other. You can fill in the information found here: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mobile-mail/imap-server-settings-sln4075.html

Comment: I spent two hours manually setting up the AT&T / Bellsouth / Yahoo mail account on a friend's new iPhone. I think the main problem is that the mail server addresses end with yahoo.com, but the email address ends with bellsouth.net. I kept trying (incorrectly) to make these consistent - both ending in .net (or in .com), which never worked. I deleted everything and started over. The second time around, I was very careful, and finally noticed the difference - and it does work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the suggestion from Apple support, and it worked for me: restart your device.

> **How to restart**
>
> 1. Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the red slider appears.
> 2. Drag the slider to turn your device completely off.
> 3. After the device turns off, press and hold the Sleep/Wake button again until you see the Apple logo.

<sup>Source: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201559</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the email account, then re-add it again. If that doesnt work, then download the yahoo mail app and see if it can work on your iPhone. If so then you may need to update your iPhone or backup and restore the iPhone software.